# How to run a shell command inside a pod in the background?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, shell, kubernetes

I am trying to run an AWS CLI command in my pod. As the pod may take some time to complete i am trying to run it in the background
Here is my command

```
kubectl -it exec  <podname> -- bash -c "aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucketname-1 --query 'Contents[?StorageClass==\"ONEZONE_IA\"].[Key,StorageClass]' --output text > /storage/ONEZONE_keys1.txt &"
```

when I run this command it becomes a defunct process
[image: process]

when I run the command without the `&` in the end it works fine
But the process gets terminated once the terminal is closed

Ultimately I just want to run this command as a cron job every day

Not sure whats wrong ,or this whole process can be done in a better way

Any help is much appreciated, Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use cronjob in k8s?

Comment: @ChuongNguyen i cant redeploy the pod any time soon and also i want the flexibility to run this command any time

Comment: Can you at least run this in a dedicated Job, instead of trying to run it inside some other process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think nohup can help on this scenario. Try to execute this command with "nohup".

Ex-

> nohup  "your command" > "redirect file-name" &

Comment: yep. Using nohup worked for me. Thanks!